# About the discrete $H^1$ norm

Tags: pde, error-estimation, l2-norm

I need to understand what is the right expression for the "discrete $H^1$-norm of a function v(which of course need to be in $H^1$).

By definition, $$||v||_{H^1}^2 = ||\nabla v||_{2}^2 + ||v||_2^2 $$

so far I'm still in the continuous case. In practice if I need to compute it I have to do the discrete $L^2$ norm of the gradient and of $v$.

For $v$ I have: $$||v||_2^2 = h \sum_{i=0}^{N} v(x_i)^2$$

But what about the $$||\nabla v||_2^2$$? How can I approximate it?

Comment: That definition for $\|v\|_2$ (which I assume to mean the $L^2$ norm) doesn't make sense because point values are not unique for $L^2$ functions and, hence, $v(x_i)$ doesn't make sense. Also, what is $x_i$  in your definition?

Comment: But I am in a discrete setting, because usually $v(x_i)$, or better $v_i$ are elements of the vector $v$ that comes from a numerical method

Comment: Which numerical method are you talking about? In finite element methods, as we have $\|v\|_2^2 = \int_\Omega v^2 \,\mathrm{d}x$, in the discrete setting we usually evaluate $\|v\|_2^2 = \sum_{K \in \mathcal{T}_h} \|v\|_{2,K}^2$ where $\mathcal{T}_h$ is a set of non-overlapping elements and $v|_K$ is polynomial so the norm is easy to evaluate explicitly and exactly.

Comment: For example finite differences, let's say I solve the equation and want to compute the error w.r.t  the analytical solution $f$. I have just the values at points $x_i$, call them $v_i$. So I consider the error *vector* $\vec{e} =( v_i - f(x_i))_i$

I want now to compute the **discrete** $H^1$ norm of this vector

Comment: It seems like you are working in a finite difference/finite volume method. You can use a finite difference approximation for the gradient. E.g., see this book https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9781447154594 or lecture notes on website of Prof. Endre Suli http://people.maths.ox.ac.uk/suli/nspde.pdf which shows how to work with discrete Sobolev norms.

Comment: Thanks for the reference @cfdlab

By the way, the *discrete* $L^2$ norm is usually computed like $\sqrt{ h \sum_{i=0}^N v(x_i)^2}$, right?

Where $h$ is the step size, and $N$ is the number of points. Of course here $h= \frac{b-a}{N}$

Comment: Sorry for my confusion which is due to my background in finite elements where there is usually no distinction between discrete and continuous norms, and if there is, we tend to use a different notation such as $\|\cdot\|_h$ to be explicit that now we're talking about discrete norms and not continuous norms.

Comment: Yes, that definition for discrete L2 norm makes sense. How you define the discrete norms may be related to the numerical scheme. You want to define it in such a way that you can prove a summation by parts formula. The notes of Suli explain this very nicely.

Comment: knl no worries :) 
@cfdlab SO basically, in the 2-D setting, it seems that one split the norm along $x$ and along $y$.

Comment: @knl There is nice way to do similar analysis in finite differences as one does in FEM and the book/notes of Suli show this. Yes, you use finite differences along x and y to define the discrete norms in 2d, and this is all explained in the notes I linked, including how to use it for finite volume analysis, where the solution now represents cell averages.

Comment: It would be useful if you expand your question with the method that you are using.

Comment: Indeed - tell us what $v_h$ is. If it is a finite element field, then the L2 norm is equivalent to $\sqrt{V^TMV}$ where $V$ are the nodal values, and $M$ is the mass matrix. The $H^1$ seminorm is equivalent to $\sqrt{V^TAV}$ with the Laplace matrix $A$.

Comment: Honestly, I only saw finite difference method up to now. But I read in my notes that one can define a discrete version of the $H^1$ norm, and I was just wondering "how".

Comment: You can add in the questions that you are interested in Finite Difference methods. That can only help people to answer your question better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming 1-D and equidistant gridpoints with spacing $h$ and some form of homogenous boundary conditions, we can use $\|\nabla v\|^2\approx -h\sum_{i=1}^nv(x_i)D_2v(x_i)$, where $D_2$ is a finite difference discretization of the Laplacian operator, which is usually some variant of a tridiagonal matrix with values $(1,-2,1)/h^2$ along the sub/main/super diagonal, respectively. I'm pretty sure this approximation is $O(h)$. This formula comes from integration by parts:

$$
-\int_\Omega v\Delta vdx = \int_\Omega\|\nabla v\|^2dx-\int_{\partial\Omega}v\nabla v\cdot dS.
$$
Any boundary conditions that make the boundary terms disappear will make this approximation work. This can also be extended to higher dimensions as long as you can approximate the Laplacian and the integral well, which are usually not too hard if you are already discretizing things in some sort of scheme.